# combine two images one transparent to another under Android

Tags: java, android, android-image

I have an android project to process images, I have two images, I want to overlay one over another (blending). To combine these two images, it’s a bit simple, using drawing on canvas:
I used this code:

```
public static Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bottomImg, Bitmap topImg) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay =   Bitmap.createBitmap(bottomImg.getWidth(),bottomImg.getHeight(),bottomImg.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bottomImg, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(topImg, 0, 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

It works well, but It doesn’t manipulate the transparency of overlaed image.  Actually I want the top image to be transparent, in order to see how it matches the bottom one. It’s something to access alpha channel or to do it manually, Can someone help me to do this task.

Answer (score -1):

You can try :

```
topImg.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

This will set all the pixels to transparent.